# sql question - outer join seems not to work

Tags: sql-server

using: sql server

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have two tables one with 70 companies (company info, etc) and one table recording the incident numbers of those companies.

I like my sql result to return every company name whether a match is found or not. I thought an outer join will help, but it looks like my where clause is preventing this from happening:

I have tried full join, outerjoin, left join, same results .....

====> However if i remove the where clause then I get *all* companies names.

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_num, TS_NAME
FROM TTS_INCIDENTS RIGHT OUTER JOIN TS_COMPANIES
ON TS_COMPANIES.TS_ID=TTS_INCIDENTS.TS_COMPANYID
WHERE TS_ACTIVEINACTIVE = 0 AND (TS_INCIDENTTYPE=10 OR TS_INCIDENTTYPE=11)
GROUP BY TS_NAME
ORDER BY TS_NAME
```

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: `However if i remove the where clause` is the clue.  The WHERE clause is applied after the OUTER JOIN, and so is being applied to NULLs; Either re-code to deal with NULLs or simply move the conditions into the JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if I don't know which relation holds which columns in your example, I'm pretty sure you actually want to do this:

```
FROM TS_COMPANIES LEFT OUTER JOIN TTS_INCIDENTS
  ON TS_COMPANIES.TS_ID = TTS_INCIDENTS.TS_COMPANYID
 AND TS_ACTIVEINACTIVE = 0 
 AND (TS_INCIDENTTYPE = 10 OR TS_INCIDENTTYPE = 11)
```

i.e. select from companies and left outer join incidents to the companies, using the incident predicates as left outer join criteria, not as select criteria.

<strike>Note, in most RDBMS, a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` usually has a heavy performance impact and should be avoided if possible</strike> (don't remember where I've read this. Might be an outdated fact).

Comment: Are you suggesting that a RIGHT OUTER JOIN has worse performance than a LEFT OUTER JOIN, or simply that outer joins perform worse than inner joins. If you're suggesting the former than I'd really love to see a reference on that as it sounds implausible. To be fair, I always use LEFT OUTER JOIN for readability purposes, but not for performance reasons.

Comment: @John, I don't remember where I had read this. It was about it being more difficult to allocate space in temporary table spaces when right joining rather than when left joining. But I can't find it now.

Comment: @Kuru, now in turn, I'd like to see a reference about the order of fields in the ON clause being of any relevance... :)

Comment: Oops -- I meant it's the order of tables around the Join.  Assuming you want to see all parents (with or without children), A parent left-joins a child, which is equivalent to a child right-joins a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need make to corrections:

- change the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.
- add an `OR TTS_INCIDENTS.TS_COMPANYID is null` to the WHERE clause

modifying the join is going to put the priority on all COMPANIES, instead of all INCIDENTS, as you have it now.
modifying the WHERE clause will allow Comapnies with NO INCIDENTS to also show-up in the list.

Comment: An `is null` check in the `where` clause is a lot less readable than moving the predicate to the join condition... IMO

Comment: What's more important is that when using outer joins, a predicate in the join condition can produce a different result set than a predicate in the WHERE clause, because of unmatched rows.

Comment: @Lukas -- that's a personal style, not a best practice.  I don't care if he uses JOIN or WHERE -- but since he used WHERE originally, I just stuck with that.

Comment: @John -- There is no 'best practice' that says doing it in the Join is better than doing it in the the Where.  It's usually just a personal preference / what you're used to, but I assure you, it's very common (and just as accurate) to do it in either place.  If you ever have a situation where you're not sure, you can look at the execution plan to verify.  In this case, the query optimizer gives the same execution plan for either method.

Comment: @kuru -- I don't mean to be hostile but that simply isn't true. SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.A1 = B.B1 AND B.B2 = 5 will return a different result set than SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.A1 = B.B1 WHERE B.B2 = 5. The first query will return a result row for every row in A including data from matching rows from B that have B2 = 5; the second query is functionally equivalent to an INNER JOIN, since a result row will only be returned for records in both A and B where B2 = 5. See Phil's response for details.

Comment: @John -- if you write my SQL for me and then critize me for it...  Well never mind.  You misunderstand -- I never said you can simply copy/paste a JOIN clause into a WHERE clause.  What I said was, you can filter a data-set in either place.  Your two queries don't return identical results because of how you wrote them.  In the second (using the WHERE), you would write 'WHERE B2 = 5 OR B2 is null'.  This is straight-forward, common-practice.  The 'OR is null' part is implicit when you use a LEFT join, but if you want to use a WHERE instead, then you have to include it explicitly.

Comment: @kuru - Ah, I see what you're saying. I read your comment to mean that you could use an identical filter in either the ON clause or the WHERE clause with no effect on your results. I see now that's not what you're saying, which is good. Adding the IS NULL check in the WHERE clause will work most of the time, for sure. I do see a case where the IS NULL check could be confusing though, but it's obtuse: you want to return all rows from A and matching rows from B where B2 IS NULL. Then you need to put it in the ON clause.

Comment: @John -- it's actually possible to do this entirely in the WHERE, with no JOIN clause at all.  This is referred to as a "Traditional" join. Likewise, it's possible to do it entirely in the JOIN (per your preference), with no WHERE clause at all.  This is referred to as an "ANSI" join.  There is some debate over whether or not it's a best-practice to keep your relational logic (table joins) separate from your filter logic (where). Do some research if you're really curious about this -- google "traditional versus ansi join" for starters -- it's a nerdy thing to do, but interesting in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If the WHERE clause is against the outer table in the JOIN, it effectively makes the JOIN an INNER JOIN (this is actually a very common mistake).  It's hard to tell which table your WHERE clause criteria works against, since you don't qualify the tables.

However, my guess is you need to make the WHERE clauses a condition of the JOIN.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS total_num, 
    TS_NAME 
FROM 
    TTS_INCIDENTS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TS_COMPANIES ON 
        TS_COMPANIES.TS_ID=TTS_INCIDENTS.TS_COMPANYID 
        AND TS_ACTIVEINACTIVE = 0 AND (TS_INCIDENTTYPE=10 OR TS_INCIDENTTYPE=11) 
GROUP BY 
    TS_NAME 
ORDER BY 
    TS_NAME
```