# sql question - outer join seems not to work

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql question - outer join seems not to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832994/sql-question-outer-join-seems-not-to-work)

With below query I get 50 results:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_num, TS_NAME
FROM TS_COMPANIES RIGHT OUTER JOIN TTS_INCIDENTS
ON (TS_COMPANIES.TS_ID=TTS_INCIDENTS.TS_COMPANYID AND TS_LEVEL2TECH=0)
WHERE TS_ACTIVEINACTIVE = 0 AND (TS_INCIDENTTYPE=10 OR TS_INCIDENTTYPE=11) 
GROUP BY TS_NAME
ORDER BY  TS_NAME
```

However if I remove TS_LEVEL2TECH=0 from the ON clause, I get 70 results.

How do I filter TS_LEVEL2TECH=0 and still get the 70 results?

Comment: cularis, the sql query is different, hence reason for repost.

Answer (score 0):

This is ambiguous because you are not really saying where TS_LEVEL2TECH is from, TS_COMPANIES or TTS_INCIDENTS, some table alias would really help here. (Same applies to TS_NAME etc)